# Center UISCrollView and Zoom to 1.0 in one smooth animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

There are several posts answering similar situations, but none are explaining to me why this is happening.
Please have a look at the code below where `slider` is a UIScrollView and `centerRect` is the CGRect we want to wind up looking at when animation is complete. 
The goal is the have `slider` zoom out to `slider.zoomScale` 1.0 and center when tapped. I have tried a variety of methods for doing this, and I have had some success, but my current solution looks shoddy.
The best case would be a smooth animation that always winds up displaying the same final rect, which happens to be centered in this situation.

I'd like to know why zoomToRect:animated does not do what I expect, and if you can help with an idea about how to make this smoother that would be a big bonus.

Method 1:
If zoomed in and scrolled off to the left somewhere this zooms out but is not centered.
Really you should only need to call zoomToRect:animated: and this has the exact same effect. if the scrollView is not centered it will not be centered after the animation. A second tap centers the scrollview.

```
[slider zoomToRect:centerRect animated:YES];
[slider scrollRectToVisible:centerRect animated:YES];
```

Method 2:
this behaves in the same way.

```
-(void) scrollToCenter{
    CGRect centerRect = slider.frame;
    centerRect.origin.x = (slider.contentSize.width / 2) - (centerRect.size.width / 2);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                          [slider scrollRectToVisible:centerRect animated:NO];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                          [slider zoomToRect:centerRect animated:YES];
                     }];
}
```

Method 3:
This works but creates a clumsy two-part animation that frankly looks just bad.

```
-(void) scrollToCenter{
    CGRect centerRect = slider.frame;
    centerRect.origin.x = (slider.contentSize.width / 2) - (centerRect.size.width / 2);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [slider setContentOffset:centerRect.origin animated:NO];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [slider setZoomScale:1.0 animated:YES];
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Proof positive that posting on Stack Overflow is helpful.
As soon as I posted this I tried something I thought I had tried before.
This works:

I'd still like to know why zoomToRect:animated does not do what I expect

```
-(void) scrollToCenter{
    CGRect centerRect = slider.frame;
    centerRect.origin.x = (slider.contentSize.width / 2) - (centerRect.size.width / 2);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [slider setContentOffset:centerRect.origin animated:NO];
                         [slider setZoomScale:1.0 animated:NO];
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: After you set the centerRect do the following `centerRect.origin.x = 0` `centerRect.origin.y=0` and try again.

Comment: Yep, I tried that. Yes it does indeed center correctly. What happens next is interesting. All of this animation is taking place inside a view while the view itself is also being resized in another animation. Basically the scroll view is closing, so to speak. When  we set these values to zero there is a slight hitch in the animation. Done with the subtraction this way it works even while being rescaled within the parent view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the method `zoomToRect:animated:`. The `rect` used by this method has to be in the space of the view returned by `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` (which will return the view used for zooming). So if you are returning the scroll view frame and if the coordinates of the scroll view are not (0,0) then the rect that you are passing won't be the "center" of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please forgive me if I am being dim, but I followed your answer as I understand it with this code:`-(void) scrollToCenter{
    CGRect centerRect = slider.frame;
    centerRect.origin = CGPointZero;
    
    [slider zoomToRect:centerRect animated:YES];`

Comment: The result is that the rect zooms out and slides to zero. The rect in this case is the same height as contentSize but not as wide - therefore it is within the space of contentSize if that is what you mean. Done this way using CGPointZero the view returns to scale 1.0 and moves all the way to the left, and never centers.